# Is there a generic Collections library wrapping non-generic Collections?

Tags: java, java1.4

I have to work was a little bit outdated JVM which supports only Java 1.4. I would like to use generics in my code, which is possible according to this article http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp02277/index.html.  Unfortunately, Collections classes in our library are not generic and they cannot be replaced (which means I cannot use http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jsr14-2.4-ea-demo-oth-JPR/). An obvious solution is to write generic wrappers for all main classes - ArrayList, HashMap, HashSet and create generic interfaces Map, etc. This is quite a work to do, so I am wondering if there might be already a library which provides this functionality.

Comment: "little bit outdated"?  Try a lot outdated.  JDK 5 has passed its support life, and JDK 7 is the current standard.  I'd recommend upgrading to JDK 6 at a minimum.

Comment: I think I don't get the problem. If you develop you code without generics, so you don't need to add them, if you wish torun at a 1.4 JVM. If your code is written with generics, I think the type-erasure will remove theem from the *.class file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you compile your code for a JVM 1.4?

If your code is compiled for Java5 (6 or 7) you'll probably get a "bad version in class file" -Error.

If you use any compiled library, all have to be compiled for Java 1.4.

Comment: I can compile with -source 1.5 and -target jsr14. In this case I can use generics, but my collections library is not generic.

Comment: Just wantet to clarify, that ANY code has to be compiled for Java 1.4